# .htaccess rewrite url when using get values

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, get

I'm trying to turn http://www.starsqa.com/lala.php?fname=bob into http://starsQA.com/lala/bob

```
      <form action="lala.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
    </form> 
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>.<br>
```

I tried this on the .htaccess, but nothing happened

```
Redirect 302 /lala.php?fname=bob http://www.starsQA.com/lala/bob.php
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, which URL do you want the user to see in their browser?

Comment: http://starsQA.com/lala/bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send visitors from `http://www.starsqa.com/lala/bob` to `http://www.starsqa.com/lala.php?fname=bob`:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala/bob$ /lala.php?fname=bob [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala/bob/$ /lala.php?fname=bob [L]
```

If you want a general pattern where fname can be any name, try this:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala/([a-zA-Z0-9:\@.\-\+]{1,100})$ /lala.php?fname=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala/([a-zA-Z0-9:\@.\-\+]{1,100})/$ /lala.php?fname=$1 [L]
```

If instead you want to send visitors from `http://www.starsqa.com/lala.php?fname=bob` to `http://www.starsqa.com/lala/bob` :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala.php?fname=bob$ /lala/bob [L]
```

And similarly, a more general pattern for this would be:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/lala.php?fname=([a-zA-Z0-9:\@.\-\+]{1,100})$ /lala.php/$1 [L]
```

Last Example (sending a user from `starsQA.com/jen-lilley-contact` to `starsQA.com/contact-id=6`) :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/jen-lilley-contact$ /contact-id=6 [L]
```

By the way, do not forget to restart Apache.

How to restart Apache depends on your platform configuration. What OS are you running it on?

Comment: What I have written as the answer will work if a user were to type http://www.starsqa.com/lala/bob but instead you want to redirect the request to http://www.starsqa.com/lala.php?fname=bob. 
Are you saying you want the reverse of that? That is, you want the users to type http://www.starsqa.com/lala.php?fname=bob instead?

Comment: i can add it under this stuff right? Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

Comment: how do i reset apache on a live site?

Comment: i'll give you a better example user entered in http://starsQA.com/jen-lilley-contact and it gives them http://starsQA.com/contact-id=6 but user sees link they entered in still

Comment: os = windows and the site is live and not on a visual server like xampp

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into mod_rewrite, see example and explanation here: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/lala\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fname=bob$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.starsQA.com/lala/bob.php [R=302,QSD,L]
```

Comment: made no change to the url sadly

Comment: Yea, that is the part that you want

Comment: i just changed id to fname and ended up with this url http://www.starsqa.com/lala/bob.php?fname=bob aka 404 not found

Comment: Have a look at the QSD flag, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/lala/(.*)$ /lala.php?fname=$1 [R=302,L]
```

opposite?

```
RewriteRule ^/lala.php?fname=(.*)$ /lala/$1.php [R=302,L]
```